# Where to store git repo to run swa efficiently using wsl2?

Tags: npm, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2, npm-start

I'm trying to run my static web app using Windows Subsystem for Linux (2), but I can't figure out where on my computer I should store the git repository to be able to run it decently quickly. I have tried storing it on under `/mnt/c/{workfolder}`, but it takes several minutes to start up (using `npm run start`), and I have to rerun to see any changes. This is useless when I'm trying to work...

I have also tried to store it in `/mnt/wsl/{workfolder}`, and in that case it starts up quickly and I can see my changes without rerunning the app. However, it seems to disappears when I restart my computer.

Where should I store the git repository to be able to run the app quickly and see changes without rerunning? I'm assuming there's something I'm not understanding, help me get this it you know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want it somewhere on the ext4 partition of the WSL distribution.  Typically, the best place is going to be under your WSL `/home/<username>` folder.

I would recommend:

```
mkdir ~/src
# or
mkdir ~/projects
# or something similar
```

Then create subdirectories for each project in that directory.

Why the others don't work:

- `/mnt/c` is the Windows `C:` drive.  That drive is mounted into WSL2 using the 9P network file system, and yes, it's (a) slow, and (b) does not support `inotify`, so apps cannot register for notifications of changes to files.
- `/mnt/wsl` is a tmpfs mount.  It's really there for holding things that need to be *shared* between all running WSL instances.  The auto-generated `resolv.conf` that you see there is one of those things.  You can also use it for copying a file from one WSL distribution to another -- Simply copy the file to `/mnt/wsl`, start another WSL distribution, and copy or move the file out.

  But yes, all tmpfs mounts are ephemeral and will terminate when the last WSL2 distribution/instance terminates.